# Unable to initialize an array or fill an array with data

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a class that I will initialize from another class within that class there a property a with class[] as type, how do i initialize and fill that array with value {1,"something"}, I am unable to get to it,  Thanks. At the very bottom what I tried so far is coded

///Calss A

```
public partial class classA_1: object,System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

private classB_1[] numberOfUnitField;


/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayAttribute(Order=0)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlArrayItemAttribute("unitNumberDetail", IsNullable=false)]
public classB_1[] numberOfUnit {
            get {
                return this.numberOfUnitField;
            }
            set {
                this.numberOfUnitField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("numberOfUnit");
            }
        }
}
```

///Class B

```
 public partial class classB_1 : object, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {

        private string numberOfUnitsField;

        private string typeOfUnitField;

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="integer", Order=0)]
        public string numberOfUnits {
            get {
                return this.numberOfUnitsField;
            }
            set {
                this.numberOfUnitsField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("numberOfUnits");
            }
        }

        /// <remarks/>
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Order=1)]
        public string typeOfUnit {
            get {
                return this.typeOfUnitField;
            }
            set {
                this.typeOfUnitField = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged("typeOfUnit");
            }
        }

        public event System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
            System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventHandler propertyChanged = this.PropertyChanged;
            if ((propertyChanged != null)) {
                propertyChanged(this, new System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

Coded so far:

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
ClassA_1 a = new ClassA_1 ();


            Hashtable hash = new Hashtable();
            hash.Add("1", "PX");
            hash.Add("200", "RC");
            int i = 0;      

            int d = hash.Keys.Count;

            b.numberOfUnit = new classB_1 [d];


            foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in hash)
            { 
               //throws an error object not instantiated on the following code              
                b.numberOfUnit[i].numberOfUnits = entry.Key.ToString();
                b.numberOfUnit[i].typeOfUnit = entry.Value.ToString();
                i++;
            } 
}
}
```

**Final working code:**

```
Dictionary<int, string> hash = new Dictionary<int, string>();
 hash.Add(1, "PX");
   hash.Add(200, "RC");

 b.numberOfUnit = hash.Select(h => new ClassB_1
                                                    {
                                                        numberOfUnits = h.Key.ToString(),
                                                        typeOfUnit = h.Value.ToString()
                                                    })
                                                             .ToArray();
```

Comment: `i` is not referenced in the `foreach` other than increment, and you have `0` and `1` indexes hard coded. Don't think that is what you want.

Comment: changed 0 and 1  to i

Comment: why is the array initialized outside the class it lives in?

Comment: its a service provider file pattern I am just using those to input my data for various queries I can't change anything in those files, but I guess oop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating the array, but since the array is an array of reference types, each reference needs to be initialized as well.  Also you are not using `i` in the loop - I think you want:

```
b.numberOfUnit = new classB_1 [d];

foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in hash)
{ 
   //throws an error object not instantiated on the following code              

    b.numberOfUnit[i] = new classB_1();
    b.numberOfUnit[i].numberOfUnits = entry.Key.ToString();
    b.numberOfUnit[i].typeOfUnit = entry.Value.ToString();
    i++;
}
```

Note that you could also use Linq to create the array:

```
b.numberOfUnit = hash.Select(h => new classB_1 {
                                                numberOfUnits = h.Key.ToString(),
                                                typeOfUnit = h.Value.ToString()
                                               })
                     .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks changed from storage type from hashtable to dictionary and both of the codes work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're attempting to initialize a array of reference types, you can't use [Array.Initialize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.initialize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but you can use Linq.

```
private MyClass[] _myArray = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(i => new MyClass()).ToArray();
```